# expected expression before | token

Tags: c

tengo una duda con respecto al error de syntaxis que me esta apareciendo aqui, cual es el motivo por el cual no me permite poner ninguna operacion logica  para los gPio, soy un tanto principiante en la programacion de micros y c en general asi que seria de mucha ayuda si me pudieran explicar que estoy haciendo mal, los pines estan declarados en otro archivo el cual esta siendo llamado en el main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "board.h"
#include "peripherals.h"
#include "pin_mux.h"
#include "clock_config.h"
#include "MKL27Z644.h"
#include "fsl_debug_console.h"
#include "LEDs_PortD.h"
#define DELAY (0x10000);

extern GPIO_Type rGpioD;
void vfnInit_PORTD(void);
void vfnInciso1();
void vfnInciso2();
void vfnInciso3();
int main(void)
{

//  volatile uint32_t dwDelay=DELAY;
//  uint8_t bvariable;
//  uint8_t *pbResult;
    /* Init board hardware. */
    BOARD_InitBootClocks();
    vfnInit_PORTD();
//
//    pbResult = bpfnByteAddress(aTest,2,3);
//
//    vfnMemCpy(aTest,bTest,3);

    while(1)
    {
        vfnInciso1();
        vfnInciso2();
//      vfnInciso3();
//      vfnInciso4();
//      vfnInciso5();
//      vfnInciso6();
//      vfnInciso7();
//      vfnInciso8();
//      vfnInciso9();
    }
}
void vfnInciso1()
{
    rGpioD.PTOR = 1u << P1;
}

void vfnInciso2()
{
    rGpioD.PDOR = 1u << P0;
    rGpioD.PDOR = 1u << P1;
    rGpioD.PDOR = 1u << P0|1u << P1; //error//
    rGpioD.PDOR = 1u << P2;
    rGpioD.PDOR = 1u << P0 | 1u << P2;//errror//
    rGpioD.PDOR = 1u << P1 | 1u << P2;//error//
    rGpioD.PDOR = 1u << P0 | 1u << P1 | 1u << P2;//error
    rGpioD.PDOR = 1u << P3;
    rGpioD.PDOR = 1u << P7;
}
```

Comment: Utiliza paréntesis en las operaciones, al igual que lo hacemos en la vida real con los números. Mira qué orden de operación quieres tener y asigna paréntesis en las líneas que lo necesites. Además, si estás trabajando bit a bit está bien que trabajas con `|`, en cambio, si estás trabajando con registros, emplea el operador OR: `||`

Comment: ¿NO habrás definido `P0`, `P1`, etc, como lo has hecho con `DELAY`, poniéndole un punto y coma al final, no?

Comment: En efecto mi estimado  si fue la declaracion de p0 y p, muchas gracias!!!!!!